# Is there any easy quick way to find the basis of the following space?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any easy way to find the basis of the following space?I was asked in an exam where for each question I can have 2,3 min to think.

$V=\{(x,y,z,w)\in\mathbb{R}^4: x+y-z=0,y+z+w=0,2x+y-3z-w=0\}$

Thank you.

Comment: More generally, if you perform elementary row operations to transform the matrix into it's reduced row echelon form, that will tell you which columns will form a basis.

Comment: There is no such thing as *the* basis. There are infinitely many possible answers to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write the first equation as $z=x+y$ and the second as $w=-y-z=-x-2y$. Quickly check that the third is then an identity and therefore adds no new information. Clearly $x$ and $y$ can be taken to be arbitrary parameters, and we’re looking at

$$\big\{x(1,0,1,-1)+y(0,1,1,-2):x,y\in\Bbb R\big\}\;,$$

with basis $\{(1,0,1,-1),(0,1,1,-2)\}$.

Answer (score 1):

I would write it in matrix form: \begin{equation} \begin{bmatrix} 1&1&-1&0 \\ 0&1&1&1 \\ 2&1&-3&-1 \\ 0&0&0&0 \end{bmatrix}. \end{equation} 
Observing that two times row 1 - row 2 = row 3, we can eliminate row 3, and then solve the resulting homogeneous system with two parameters: \begin{equation} \begin{bmatrix} x\\y\\z\\w \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 2t+s\\-t-s\\t\\s \end{bmatrix} = t \begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\\1\\0 \end{bmatrix}+s\begin{bmatrix}1\\-1\\0\\1 \end{bmatrix}. \end{equation}
So a basis is then $\{(2,-1,1,0),(1,-1,0,1)\}$.